# Inherit Singleton

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

Quick question. Is there anyway to inherit a singleton so that the child class is a singleton? I have searched around but every singleton I can find is implemented per class, and not in a generic fashion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is a generic way. You can implement a Singleton via [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), like:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
protected:
    Singleton() noexcept = default;

    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;

    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

    virtual ~Singleton() = default; // to silence base class Singleton<T> has a
    // non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]

public:
    static T& get_instance() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value)
    {
        // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
        // Instantiated on first use.
        // Thread safe in C++11
        static T instance{};

        return instance;
    }
};
```

then derive from it to make your child a Singleton:

```
class MySingleton: public Singleton<MySingleton>
{
    // needs to be friend in order to 
    // access the private constructor/destructor
    friend class Singleton<MySingleton>; 
public:
    // Declare all public members here
private:
    MySingleton()
    {
        // Implement the constructor here
    }
    ~MySingleton()
    {
        // Implement the destructor here
    }
};
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d86b3cc6cabab74)

Answer (score 0):

A singleton has a static `getInstance()` method that upon first invocation creates the single instance of the class, and therefore is statically-bound to the type of singleton class being instantiated.  I don't see the immediate utility of having a Singleton hierarchy.  But if you insist on having one, you might consider making the `getInstance` method `virtual` and overriding it in the class extending your parent Singleton.

```
class Singleton {
    public virtual Singleton * getInstance() const
    {
        // instantiate Singleton if necessary
        // return pointer to instance
    }
    ...
};

class MySingleton : public Singleton {
    // overrides Singelton's getInstance
    public virtual MySingleton * getInstance() const
    {
        // instantiate MySingleton if necessary
        // return pointer to instance
    }
};
```

Of course, a robust implementation would store and return smart pointers.